# How to change json_to_sheet header

Tags: reactjs, json, xlsx

json_to_sheet uses the titles from my data file and I would like to use the 'header' titles instead. You can find some of the code below.

**File with the data**

I have a separate document with all the data

```
export const data = [
    {
      naam: 'Patricia van Oort',
      hf: '',
      fc: '',
      visitekaartje: '',
      actief: '',
      doorkiesnr: '',
      mobiel: '06-123459',
      email: 'patricia.oort@livits.nl',
      opmerking: '',
      lid: '',
    },
],
```

**app.js**

In this document I make download the data to an .xlsx file

```
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [


      {
        accessorKey: "naam",
        header: "Naam", //I want to use this header name instead of the names in the file with the data
      },
],
[],
);

const ExportExcel = ({ excelData, fileName}) => {
  const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
  const fileExtension = '.xlsx';

  const ExportExcel = async () => {
      const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(excelData);
      const wb = {Sheets: {'Sheet 1' : ws}, SheetNames: ['Sheet 1']};
      const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array'});
      const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], {type: fileType});
      Filesaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);
  }

  return (
      
      <Tooltip title="Excel Export">
      <Button
      onClick={(e) => ExportExcel(fileName)}
      startIcon={<FileDownloadIcon />}
      variant="contained"
    >
      Excel download
    </Button>
   </Tooltip>
     <ExportExcel excelData={data} fileName={'Export'}/>
  )
}
```